# I am not getting camera position at my location using Google Map in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using Google Map on iOS, and I am getting the marker at my location but not getting camera position to my location. I have seen lots of tutorials but not getting any solution.

My code is :

```
mapView = GMSMapView()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        // locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()

        // GOOGLE MAPS SDK: COMPASS
        mapView.settings.compassButton = true

        // GOOGLE MAPS SDK: USER'S LOCATION
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        mapView.animate(toBearing: 0)


 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        if  let location = locations.last
        {
            print("location\(String(describing: location))")

         //   mapView.clear()
            let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude))
            marker.map = mapview
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                                                      longitude: location.coordinate.longitude,
                                                      zoom: 50)

        }
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

Comment: Have you read doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check GMSMapView.padding. It can differ from the rect of your GMSMapView, then camera will point to another position.